# Post to producer and request from consumer in one http request

Tags: flask, apache-kafka

I have some data that I need to process by external library, I send the data through POST request in Flask, to a Kafka producer, after processing the external library send the data to a consumer.

In the app.py file I have something like this:

```
from flask import request, jsonify
from app.common import kafka_buffer


@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process_data():
    data = request.get_json()
    response = kafka_buffer(data)
    return jsonify([r for r in response])
```

In the common.py file I have something like this:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer


producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
consumer = KafkaConsumer('some_consumer', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')


kafka_buffer(text):
    producer.send('some_producer', bytes(text, 'utf-8'))
    for message in consumer:
        yield message.value
```

When I try to get the data from the consumer as a response, I get a timeout error, and never get the processed data, it just hangs there.

What I want is to have the processed data be sent back as a HTTP response in one go, I mean in the same request.

Any ideas?